# Automated Request parameter generation using swagger in DefaultTest.class file

Tags: java, android, junit, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to generated Model Request parameter automatically in test cases
for example , in my model there are two variable with setter and getter methods as shown below.

```
public class LoginModel{
public String username ="abc";
public String password = "123";

public void setUserName(String username){
    this.username = username;
}
public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserName(){
    return this.username;
}
public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}
```

}

and i wanted to be generated by swagger or using custom Templete in DefaultTest.class file.

```
 LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
```

Please give any suggestion.
thanks...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a solution.

Here you are not providing swagger specification file.

You have to change your swagger specification like,

```
LoginModel:
    - type: object
      properties:
        username :
          type: string
          example: abc
          default: abc
        password :
          type: string
          example: 123
          default: 123
```

Now you have to create a custom template for pojo.mustache (you will found this in swagger swagger-codegen in recource folder).

you have to modify pojo.mustache here.

```
{{#isPrimitiveType}} 
  private {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}} = {{{defaultValue}}};
{{/isPrimitiveType}}
{{^isPrimitiveType}}
  private {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}} = new {{{datatypeWithEnum}}}();
{{/isPrimitiveType}}
```

after modifing this you will achive codegen like you want...!

i hope it will help...!
thanks.

Comment: hey @Sanjay Chauhan i got the solution from your answer.Thank you very much man..!!!